# Angular - Pushing elements into an array in a loop updates all the preexisting values of the array with the new value

Tags: arrays, angular, date

I am pushing the dates of the week into an array.

If you can refer the code, in the // good value line
The array has the correct value

But each time the         dates.setDate(dates.getDate() + 1 );
executes

All the array values are automatically updated with the new value.
Instead of just pushing the new element in the array, it pushes the new element in the array and replaces all the elements of the array with the new element

```
  this.mondayDate = this.getMonday(this.viewDate);
  let dates = this.mondayDate;
  this.datesOfTheWeek = [];
  this.datesOfTheWeek.push(this.mondayDate);
  console.log(this.datesOfTheWeek);
  for(let i in [1,2,3,4,5,6]){
    console.log(this.datesOfTheWeek); // good value in the array
    dates.setDate(dates.getDate() + 1 );
    console.log(this.datesOfTheWeek); // bad value in the array

    this.datesOfTheWeek.push(dates);
    console.log(this.datesOfTheWeek);
  }

  console.log(this.datesOfTheWeek);
```

1st iteration: //contains only monday date- output from //bad value

Array(1) [Tue May 21 2019 15:17:46 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’E…]

2nd iteration: // pushing tuesday date- output from //bad value

Array(2) [Wed May 22 2019 15:17:46 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’E…, Wed May 22 2019 15:17:46 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’E…]

The array value at the end is

Array(6) [Sun May 26 2019 15:17:46 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’E…, Sun May 26 2019 15:17:46 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’E…, Sun May 26 2019 15:17:46 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’E…, Sun May 26 2019 15:17:46 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’E…, Sun May 26 2019 15:17:46 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’E…, Sun May 26 2019 15:17:46 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’E…]

But it should contain the dates from may 20 to may 26

Answer (score 1):

That's because `dates` looks to be a Date object, not a primitive (so, if you mutate it, all the references to it will point to the mutated value). You need to create a copy: instead of

```
    dates.setDate(dates.getDate() + 1 );
    console.log(this.datesOfTheWeek); // bad value in the array

    this.datesOfTheWeek.push(dates);
```

do something like

```
    let newDate = new Date(dates);
    newDate.setDate(dates.getDate() + 1 );
    console.log(this.datesOfTheWeek);

    this.datesOfTheWeek.push(newDate);
```